# Docker Image Pull repeated failure and retries

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I`m new to development on windows and I just installed docker on Windows 10.

When I try to run/pull hello-world container, it stops abruptly and displays following message,

```
C:\Users\harshaa>docker pull library/hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
e46172273a4e: Retrying in 3 seconds
1f7d468f830c: Retrying in 3 seconds
35655e48c5c5: Download complete
8159aad5f944: Download complete
```

After this it resumes and same behaviour repeats.

Comment: Your country or company's network to `dockerhub` is not good, try more times if failure. If any organization afford mirror in your country, suggest use the mirror.

Comment: I thought it has to be a problem with my office connection, so I switched to a hotspot and tried. Similar behaviour.